# Unity create new scene is acting very weird having yellow default material and relative transform

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I create a new scene in unity, I get every new object created in this new scene a little bit yellow (even if the material of everything is the default with white color). And when I create an object as child object to any existing object, it takes its same dimensions, and it has to be in the root level of the hierarchy, and here is the image below, this very large upper yellowish ground has a scale of just (1,1,1). This was created by right click on the lower cube and create 3D object then selecting cube (not by just duplicating). What is happening?

These problems do not happen with the the first scene in the project, i.e. when I create a new project, these problems appear only with the second scene.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
Another problem, changing the velocity of the child component (which is above in the previous picture after changing the scales to (.01, 1, .01) to make it square) changing the velocity changes the dimensions, I'm losing control.

Comment: How is your `Light` component of your GameObject `Directonal Light` ?

Comment: same as the Light component of the Directional Light in the first scene, add to that I haven't touched it

Comment: What gives you [CreatePrimitive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CreatePrimitive.html) ?

Comment: dont get it, what do mean @Malphegal

Comment: In any script, try to call `GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);`, and assign its parent to different gameObject (or `null`). How is it going ?

Comment: same problems, when I created the child cube(which is created programmatically), it has been created with scales .01, 1, .01 and if I change them to 1, 1, 1 it becomes as . the parent cube which has scale of 100, 1,100. as u . can see, its scalled based on its parent values

Comment: I have even tried to create the a new cube in the first scene created (which is working well as I said previously) and copy past the cube, the Light source, and the camera from that scene where they are working well to the newly created scene, yet not solved

Comment: Maybe the skybox is yellow ? Window -> Rendering -> Lighting Settings.

Comment: I checked it, its the default skybox

Answer (score 2):

In the buttom right corner where it says "Auto Generate Lighting Off" click on it and a small tab will appear. Tick the box saying "Auto Generate" and PROBLEM SOLVED!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I managed only to solve the color part, if you select the directional light object, change the color to white and increase the intensity to 1.5, this will solve the problem, you can't consider this as a full solution since it does not solve the problem, it just covers it.

Comment: thanks for the answer but, I know that, I have done the same but this does not solve the problem, the Light source of the first scene which works well as I said have the same old values, whats happening, this is making me made

Answer (score -1):

It is because your directional light color is yellow.

Comment: thats wrong, I have copied it from the first scene which were working just fine, u try to create a new project, it will come with a directional light with the same rgb values. and this is not the only probelm, I have another one which is when I create a new cube as a child of the ground, it gets created with the same size as the ground as if I duplicated the ground. Thanks any way for the answer, please if you can help me, edit the answer, I am really very stressed and can't work, I have been in this s..t for 3 days.

Comment: Dude, I hope you hve figured something out in the meantime, if not can you zip me the broken project? I am super curious about what is happening.